# Cloudflare Workers - changes are not visible on live (but are in preview)

Tags: cloudflare-workers

Hello and thank you for your help.
Sadly support over at CF does not think they need to help me.

I am learning to use workers, and have written a simple HTML injector just to see it working on my site.

this is the full worker code i have:

```
async function handleRequest(req) {
  const res = await fetch(req)
  const contentType = res.headers.get("Content-Type")

  console.log('contentType: ', contentType)
  
  // If the response is HTML, it can be transformed with
  // HTMLRewriter -- otherwise, it should pass through
  if (contentType.startsWith("text/html")) {
    return rewriter.transform(res)
  } else {
    return res
  }
}




class UserElementHandler {
    async element(element) {
        
        element.before("<div class='contbox'><img src='https://coverme.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/covermeLOGO-01-1024x183.png' style='width:200px;margin:20px;'><h1>testing inserting</h1></div>", {html: true});
        
      // fill in user info using response
    }
  }

    

const rewriter = new HTMLRewriter()
.on("h1", new UserElementHandler())


addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

it just uses element.before to inject some HTML.
in the worker preview pane i can see it!
but on the live site = nothing.

this is the active URL: [https://coverme.co.il/product/%D7%A0%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-tuberosejasmine/]

these are the 4 routes i have set up to try to catch this, with and without encoding the letters:

```
coverme.co.il/product/נר-בינוני-tuberosejasmine/
*.coverme.co.il/product/נר-בינוני-tuberosejasmine/*
https://coverme.co.il/product/%D7%A0%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-tuberosejasmine/
*.coverme.co.il/product/%D7%A0%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-tuberosejasmine/*
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you've configured your routes to match "נר-בינוני" unescaped, but the browser will actually percent-encode the URL before sending to the server, therefore the route matching actually operates on percent-escaped URLs. So the actual URL is `https://coverme.co.il/product/%D7%A0%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-tuberosejasmine/`, and this does not match your route because `%D7%A0%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99` is not considered to be the same as `נר-בינוני`.

EDIT: Unfortunately, using percent-encoding in your route pattern won't fix the problem, due to a known bug. Unfortunately, it's just not possible to match non-ASCII characters in a Workers route today. We intend to fix this, but it's hard because some sites are accidentally dependent on the broken behavior, so the fix would break them.

What you can potentially do instead is match against `coverme.co.il/product/*`, and then, inside your worker, check if the path also has `נר-בינוני-tuberosejasmine`. If it does not, then your fetch event handler should simply return without calling `event.respondWith()`. This will trigger "default handling" of the request, meaning it will pass through and be sent to your origin server like normal. (Note that you will still be billed for a Workers request, though.)

So, something like this:

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  if (event.request.url.includes(
      "coverme.co.il/product/נר-בינוני-tuberosejasmine/")) {
    event.respondWith(handle(event.request));
  } else {
    return;  // not a match, use default pass-through handling
  }  
})
```

Comment: thanks you Kenton. i've tried this and it doesn't work. i left also the other routes. any other ideas? it is working in preview pane of worker, but not on regular live browsing

Comment: @tarkil Bad news, I checked and this turns out to be a known bug... Workers route patterns will not work when the route contains non-ASCII characters, whether or not you percent-encode them. The bug is that the system currently decodes the percent-encoding in the route pattern, but then tries to match them against request URLs that are always percent-encoded, so they never match. We want to fix it, but it turns out many people now depend on the broken behavior and "fixing" it would break their sites, so it's hard. :(

Comment: so, if i test on a regular URL it should work? and the only problem is the characters on the URL?

Comment: i added another route, "https://coverme.co.il/affiliate-area/" - same, my HTML does not show on the page. worker was left untouched.

Comment: @tarkil the page https://coverme.co.il/affiliate-area/ does not appear to have any <h1> tags in it, and your rewriter is triggered on <h1>, so I suppose it's expected that no rewrites are made.

Comment: thank you. you are correct, changed it to h2 and it works. thanks.